# Design pattern a user data used globally in the whole application

Tags: ios, design-patterns

I am working on an iOS project which the app needs to get user data from server. Once the user data is loaded
It is used globally in the whole application, I mean many controllers use the user data. I do not know what the best design pattern for user data is.

I did some research but people say that should not use global state.

Could you please suggest to me how to design it properly?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **Singleton** to accomplish what you want. The singleton pattern is basically a class with a factory method (a class method that returns an instance of the class) that always returns the same object when called. Usually the object is created the first time the factory method is called.

Since a singleton class always returns the same object, and you can get it by just knowing the class, it is effectively a substitute for global variables. However, since it is an object, you still have data hiding mechanism, lazy initialization and such to use.

[Read more on Singletons](https://cocoacasts.com/what-is-a-singleton-and-how-to-create-one-in-swift/)